# Updating data for D3 chart using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, jsx, updating

I have my main App.js component rendering a scatterplot with D3, which in turn renders a barplot, also with D3

When a point on the scatterpoint is clicked, based on the value of the point, one of 2 barplots is generated (on first click), or updated with new data (on subsequent clicks).

With the simplified code below, instead of updating the data on the original chart, a new bar plot is being appended to the div element with each click. How do I alter the componentDidUpdate() code in the barplot.js section so that the original barplot chart is updated?

```
//Data is input here
const scatterPlotData = [
    [5, 20], [48, 90], [250, 50], [100, 33], [330, 95],
    [410, 12], [475, 44], [25, 67], [85, 21], [220, 88]
];
const bardata1 = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];

const bardata2 = [ 1, 20, 33, 5, 7, 25, 22, 10, 1, 23,31, 2, 5, 40, 28, 27, 6, 8, 3, 5 ];


class ScatterPlot extends Component {
    createScatterPlot() {
        //d3 code here, relevant part which determines which barplot data to select  
        .on("click", function(d) {
            //If x value of scatterplot point is >= 200, choose bar plot data above
            if (d[0] >= 200) {
                component.setState({ bardata: bardata2, event: d3.event });
            } else {
                component.setState({ bardata: bardata1, event: d3.event });
            }
        })
    }
    render() {
      return  (
        <div>
        {
            //BarPlot class is called
            this.state.bardata && this.state.event &&
            <BarPlot bardata={this.state.bardata}/>
        }    
        </div>
      )
    }
}


class BarPlot extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.createBarPlot = this.createBarPlot.bind(this)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.createBarPlot()
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if(JSON.stringify(this.props.bardata) !== JSON.stringify(prevProps.bardata)) {
            this.setState({bardata: null});
            this.createBarPlot()
        }
    }
    createBarPlot() {
        //d3 code here
    }
    render() {
        return  (
            <div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

//Main app which calls the ScatterPlot class
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            pointdata: pointdata1

        }
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <header className="App-header">
          Scatter Plot via React
        </header>
        <div id = 'plot-1'>
          <ScatterPlot pointdata={this.state.pointdata} />
        </div>
        <div id="barplot"></div>
      </div>

    );

  }
```

Comment: you probably need a similar method to `createBarPlot` that would be something like `destroyBarPlot`, and would remove all of the contents of the div that you'd like to replace with the new bar plot

Comment: There isnt a way of doing this without destroying/re-rendering the entire plot?

Comment: there is, but your `createBarPlot` is probably creating elements that already exist, and it gets called every time the props update in `ComponentWillUpdate`. and so you're essentially "creating" the bar plot every time you update the props of your component - not ideal

Comment: Well, what is ideal then?

Comment: impossible to tell, you haven't included the most relevant pieces of code here...

Comment: I had more detailed code up for a few days and nobody responded. My question only concerns the react portion, which is all here, the only portion of the code I did not include here is the d3 chart building....Nevertheless, if you want more specific details, then let me know what part